# Table Header border cannot be seen after changing color

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I am trying to change the color of jtable header but after I changed it, the border/separator between two header columns went missing.
Here is my code:

```
grdDetails.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
grdDetails.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
grdDetails.setBorder(border);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? Sometimes writing of such example helps to find the problem by myself.

Comment: Have you tried grdDetails.getTableHeader().setBorder(border);

Comment: I tried that but I got the same result